# How to display progress using ProgessDialog in MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, progressdialog

I wrote an Android app using `MVVM` where I am calling `webservice` from ViewModel and storing results in RoomDB. In the View I am observing ViewModel for live data.
I need to show ProgressDialog while fetching data from Webservice using Retrofit.
Where do I need to write code to display `progressdialog` as I should not use `userinterface` widgets in other architecture components except in View component?
Can anyone help me how to handle this scenario?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can do it by calling a dialog from the activity and hide dialog in view model observer. This is how I have handled the progress dialog in my view.

**Code::**

```
    private fun callWebApi() {
    // show progress dialog 
    showLoader()

    mViewModel?.loadMethod()
        ?.observe(this, Observer { mModel: BaseModel? ->
            // hide loader
            hideLoader()
            // implement code
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is the right way. as you're dismissing alert dialog every now and then when data changes